# Diff month days over zero

Tags: php, date, time, php-carbon

I'v tow day numbers of carbon dates in php (example below only for demonstration the dates are diffrent).

```
Carbon::now()->day
```

I wan't to diff the tow days. My problem is when I have for example the 1th March 2019 and the 19th Januar 2019 and I diff 1-19 it will return -18. How can I subtract the tow days that I get day in the month before?

Comment: Hi Markus, have you taken a look at the carbon documentation for its "diff" functionality? https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
$date1->diffInDays($date2);
```